# Are there any substituents other than halogens which are ortho-para directors but ring deactivators?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

I was reading about electrophilic aromatic substitution reactions, and in every book, I found that the only example given for ortho-para directors - which deactivate the ring - were halogens. So are there any other substituents, other than halogens, which are ortho-para directors but ring deactivators? If so, do they do it like halogens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The nitroso $\ce{-NO}$ group is deactivating as well as ortho para directing just like the halogens in electrophilic aromatic substitution.

For reasons of this behaviour, refer to [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/57044/51553) question on the website.

Here are more examples from Peter Skyes' Guidebook to Mechanism in Organic Chemistry: (least deactivating to most deactivating)

> $\ce{-F}<\ce{-Cl,-Br, -I}<\ce{CH2Cl < -CH=CH-COOH < -CH=CH-NO2}$

For all these groups $\ce{-I}$ effect is more dominating than $\ce{+M}$ effect. Hence they deactivate the ring. However, when the arenium ion is formed they stabilise the ring through the $\ce{+M}$ effect (hyperconjugation in case of $\ce{CH2-Cl}$)

The book doesn't mention the nitroso group in the order but since it has very weak +M we should expect it to be after $\ce{CH2Cl}$

$\ce{Cl-, Br- , I-}$ are almost equally deactivating therefore they have been separated by a comma.