# Seeing a case where both + and - mesomeric effect is shown

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, nitro-compounds

I came up with that -N=O group shows both +M and -M and I understand that. In my textbook it was written that " -N=O group attached to benzene shows both + m and -m depending on the nature of other groups attached to benzene" I really couldn't get it,how are that groups how to see owe to which group N=O will show +m and by which it will show -m?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/57044/why-is-the-nitroso-group-a-deactivating-group-for-electrophilic-aromatic-substit

Comment: There answer is written that-N=O becomes  o-p directing in both electrophilic and nucleophilic substitution. I didn't get this why it will be o-p directing when ring is electron rich when -NO is showing -M . Shouldn't it be meta directing in nucleophilic substitution when ring is electron rich?